# Greater and equal predicate does not work- RavenDB session.Query

Tags: c#, linq, lucene, ravendb, lucene.net

I'm using session.Query for getting data from RavenDB
I want to get documents where price field greater or equal to price parameter.
I try-

`session.Query<Index.Result, Index>()
        .Where(x => x.Id == Id
         && x.Price >= Settings.Price)
  .TransformWith<Transformer, Transformer.Result>()
  .ToList();`

But I get wrong results - only 2 documents instead of 3.
If I add the predicate after the query I get the right result  =3 documents

`var a = session.Query<Index.Result, Index>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
                .TransformWith<Transformer, Transformer.Result>()
                .ToList();
var b = a.Where(x => x.Price >= Settings.Price)
         .ToList();`

Why the session.Query doesn't work correctly?

In Lucene Syntax I get the correct results - 3 documents.

`session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Index.Result, Index>()
        .Where(string.Format("Id :{0}  Price : [{1} TO *]" , Id, Price))
        .SetResultTransformer("Transformer")
        .SelectFields<Transformer.Result>()
        .ToList();`

But I want to use the session.Query syntax.
So how can I use the session.Query syntax linq syntax to get the result according to the greeter or equal predicate?

Thank in advance

Comment: What is the type of Price? Is is possible that you are passing a float when it needs a double?

Note that for numeric equality, your lucene sytanx query should be:

   Price_Range : [Dx10 TO *]

Or something like that.

Comment: The Price type is - double. Like 3.5.
Yes I wrote the right lucene query, but I don't want to use lucene directly.